# How do I use gradlew in Bamboo?

Tags: gradle, bamboo

I have a project that I would like to build in Bamboo with a specific version of Gradle. However, when Bamboo executes ./gradlew I get

```
Failing task since return code of [./gradlew clean build sonarRunner] was -1 while expected 0
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case I was checking in the script into SVN from Windows, and Bamboo was running on a RHEL server. To get ./gradlew to work, I needed to set the svn:executable property to true on the gradlew file.

[image]